# My code is skipping around.. Practicing threading

Tags: java, multithreading

My issue is that my code is skipping over itself, stopping at the loop here:

```
   while (!engineOn) {
        System.out.println("Push on. ");
        engStatus = input.nextLine();
        if (engStatus.equals("on")) {
            engineOn = true;
            System.out.println("Starting Engine ");
            rpm = idleRpm;
            System.out.println("RPM: " + rpm + "\nGear: " + gear);
        } else {
            engineOn = false;
            System.out.println("Engine off ");
        }
    }
```

in the InputThread class.

Output gets to here:

```
Output:
MultiThreaded Practice - RPM Shifter 
line 26
Push on. 
on
Starting Engine 
RPM: 800
Gear: 1
```

***Terminated..***

Ignoring other issues in the code that I have not worked out yet.

I've tried setting the threads to different priorities even. Still no luck. I've had this issue before, but I never attempted to figure out why and just moved on. Now it's important to me to know why this is happening.

Here is my code.. I've looked all over for an answer, most suggesting my code may be wrong. But since this was just a practice.. this is using too much of my free time. I'm trying to practice threading and using some random tidbits I've learned..

I'm still new to coding, let alone java.

Any hints would be helpful.

```
package Engine;

import java.util.Scanner;

import Engine.Engine.Gear;
import Engine.Engine.InputThread;
import Engine.Engine.RpmCycle;

public class App extends Thread {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("MultiThreaded Practice - RPM Shifter ");

    // System.out.println("Type start to run program. ");
    // String run = input.nextLine();

    // Call threads.. Wait on input for thread kill or gear switch
    RpmCycle rpm = new RpmCycle();
    Gear gear = new Gear();
    InputThread control = new InputThread();
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(2);

    control.setPriority(8); 
    gear.setPriority(8);
    rpm.setPriority(8);

    control.start();

    System.out.println("line 26");

    while (Engine.engineOn == true) {

        rpm.start();
        gear.start();
        control.start();

    }

    if(Engine.engineOn==false && Engine.getRpm() != 0){
    System.out.println("You lost: Engine Blown ");
    }
}
}

package Engine;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Engine {
private static int rpm = 0, idleRpm = 800, rpmLimit = 8000, gear = 1, 
maxGear = 6, waitTime = 100;
public static boolean engineOn = false, asked = false;
public static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
public static String shift = "";

public static int getRpm() {
    return rpm;
}

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static class Gear extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (shift == "" && asked != true) {
            System.out.println("Shift? ");
            if(shift.equals("1")){
                gear++;
                System.out.println(gear);
            }
            shift="";
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}

public static class RpmCycle extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (rpm <= rpmLimit) {
            System.out.println("RPM: " + rpm + "\nGear: " + gear);
            rpm += 500;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Engine Blown ");
            engineOn = false;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }

    }
}

public static class InputThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String engStatus = null;

        while (!engineOn) {
            System.out.println("Push on. ");
            engStatus = input.nextLine();
            if (engStatus.equals("on")) {
                engineOn = true;
                System.out.println("Starting Engine ");
                rpm = idleRpm;
                System.out.println("RPM: " + rpm + "\nGear: " + gear);
            } else {
                engineOn = false;
                System.out.println("Engine off ");
            }
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e + ": line 70 in input thread");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What behavior are you expect? Looks like your code inside `while (Engine.engineOn == true)` is never called cause engineOn is `false`, so the main method just exits (not paying attention to the fact that there is no need to compare boolean values with `==`)

Comment: I'm expecting the while loop to loop through, then continue on to the rest of my code. The issue is that it stops at the end of the loop. It's , from my understanding, supposed to put the thread to sleep for 100 milliseconds where it is then called again.

I can't even get it to get past the loop. It just skips in the main method to a sysout of "line 26". In the middle of posting this I managed to get the sysout"line 26" to appear first but now it still just stops at the end of the loop.

Comment: I see you edited your comment as well. I have the first 'control.start();' to have 'engineOn = true'

Comment: Im afraid that `while` condition was checked before yout `control` thread made `engineOn = true`. Try to add some logging inside your loop to check that it works as expected